# repair gpt after cloning to smaller drive

Tags: dd, gpt, cloning, partition-table

I had a gpt-partitioned drive, with unpartitioned space at the end, I used dd to clone it to another smaller drive. Unfortunately Linux won't see the partitions on the cloned drive.

My understanding is that GPT has two copies of the partition table, the primary copy at the start just after the MBR table, and the secondary one at the end. So it should be possible to fix the partitioning on the cloned drive, what if-any tools can be used to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gdisk` was able to fix the drive. It displayed some warnings, but was able to correctly read the primary copy of the GPT, adjust the location of the secondary GPT, and write the partition table back to the disk.

I also tried `fdisk` and `gparted`, but neither of them was able to correctly handle the drive. `fdisk` only saw the protective MBR. `gparted` said that the backup GPT was corrupt and it was using the primary one, but then failed to see any of the partitions on the drive.